# Не работает путь к файлу

Tags: captcha, файлы, php

Начинаю верить в мистические свойства языка html. Создал отдельно капчу. Работает нормально. Вывожу капчу, как вы и советовали, через `<img src="captcha.php">`. Теперь хочу привязать к регистрации. Создал папку captcha. Закинул туда файл, хочу вывести вот так `<img src="captcha/captcha.php">`, но не работает, переношу в корневой каталог `<img src="captcha.php">` - работает. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: может в инклюдах?

Comment: >Начинаю верить в мистические свойства языка html

в таком случае пора завязывать с программированием.  В этой сфере деятельности  мистики не бывает

Comment: ПЛЮС ТЕБЕ!!!! НАПРАВИЛ НА НУЖНУЮ МЫСЛЬ!

Comment: Вместо include() лучше require(). А также если не уверен в путях то лучше:
<img src="<? echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ?>/captcha/captcha.php"> 
> в таком случае пора завязывать с программированием. В этой сфере деятельности мистики не бывает
в HTML мистика на уровне всётаки бывает, хоть и на уровне браузера (вспоминаем IE6,7) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

А если так: `<img src="/captcha/captcha.php">`? Проверьте адрес капчи, по которому браузер пытается ее загрузить.